# Estimate $ \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}} dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, estimation

Consider the following integral for $x>0$:

$$ \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}} dy.$$

I would like to show that this integral is actually convergent. Is it possible to find an integrable upper bound for the function $y\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}}$? I could not accomplish anything in this direction.

Best wishes

Comment: You can have an explicit solution in terms of elliptic integral of the first kind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple [sum/difference of two hyperbolic trig functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Sums_of_arguments):

$$\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)=2\sinh\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\sinh\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)$$

Thus, the real question is whether or not

$$\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{\sinh\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)}}\ dy$$

converges. We may use $\sinh(x)\ge x$ for $x\ge0$ to compare this to

$$\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{x-y}}\ dy$$

which converges.  That is,

$$\begin{align}\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}}\ dy&\le\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\operatorname{csch}(x/2)}\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{\sinh\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)}}\ dy\\&\le\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\operatorname{csch}(x/2)}\int_0^x\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{x-y}}\ dy\\&=2\sqrt{x\operatorname{csch}(x/2)}\\&<\infty\end{align}$$

Comment: The OP just asked for an upper bound, so I came up with the simplest one I could.  I don't mind seeing the integral worked all the way out of course, but it wasn't necessary for this task.

Comment: No problem! @Thorsten

Comment: Nice solution, for sure plus a very good approximation. $\to +1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Nah, I think its a horrible approximation.  Not very good asymptote as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{x\ >\ 0}
{\dd y \over \root{\cosh\pars{x} - \cosh\pars{y}}} =
\int_{0}^{x}
{\dd y \over \root{\bracks{2\sinh^{2}\pars{x/2} + 1} - \bracks{2\sinh^{2}\pars{y/2} + 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{2}\int_{0}^{x/2}
{\dd y \over \root{\sinh^{2}\pars{x/2} - \sinh^{2}\pars{y}}}
\end{align}

> Lets $\ds{\sinh\pars{y} = \sinh\pars{x/2}\sin\pars{t} \iff
> t = \arcsin\pars{\sinh\pars{y}/\sinh\pars{x/2}}}$.

$$
\mbox{Note that}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\ds{\partiald{y}{t} =
{\sinh\pars{x/2}\cos\pars{t} \over \cosh\pars{y}} =
{\sinh\pars{x/2}\cos\pars{t} \over \root{1 + \sinh^{2}\pars{y}}} =
{\sinh\pars{x/2}\cos\pars{t} \over \root{1 + \sinh^{2}\pars{x/2}\sin^{2}\pars{t}}}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\root{\sinh^{2}\pars{x \over 2} - \sinh^{2}\pars{y}} = \sinh\pars{x \over 2}\cos\pars{t}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{y = {x \over 2} \implies t = {\pi \over 2}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{x}
{\dd y \over \root{\cosh\pars{x} - \cosh\pars{y}}} =
\root{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd t \over \root{1 + \sinh^{2}\pars{x/2}\sin^{2}\pars{t}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd t \over \root{1 - \bracks{\ic\sinh\pars{x/2}}^{\,2}\sin^{2}\pars{t}}} =
\bbx{\ds{\root{2}\,
\mrm{K}\pars{\ic\sinh\pars{x \over 2}}}}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{\mrm{K}}$ is the
>   [Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2.E8).

Comment: I am unable to identify where is the problem but the last expression does not seem to match numerical integration of the original expression. Would you accept to check again ? Your idea is so nice ! Sorry to disturb you. Thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici There was a typo in the final result which I already fixed. Now, it satisfies the conditions which are enumerated in the cited link. I added some details to avoid so many 'jumps'. I don't feel disturbed: Those are the 'MSE-game rules' anyway.  Thank for your remarks.