# An integral limit $\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}}\ dy$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

While solving [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192383/estimate-an-integral), I stumbled upon a strange limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}}\ dy\approx2.22$$

I'm not really sure how to go about handling such limits within the integral.  Any suggestions?

Comment: My only thoughts so far are using series expansions, but this results in limits of poles, and so I'm a bit lost...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable $u=\dfrac yx$, $dy=xdu$, one gets
$$
\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}}\ dy=\int_0^1\frac{x}{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(x \cdot u)}}\ du
$$ then one may observe that, for $0<u<1$, by applying a Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0^+$, 
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(x \cdot u)}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}
$$ giving, by using the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem),
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)}}\ dy=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\approx \color{red}{2.2214\cdots}.
$$

Comment: Nicely done!  I was getting pretty close to this, still working out my own series expansions :D

Comment: @Olivier, in your first line, how did you change the upper limit from $x$ to $1$?

Comment: @mrnovice $u=y/x$, so the upper bound becomes $x/x=1$

Comment: Ah okay, just thought there might have been some intricacies since we're taking the limit as $x$ tends to $0$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{x}
{\dd y \over \root{\cosh\pars{x} - \cosh\pars{y}}} =
\root{2}\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{x}
{\dd y \over \root{\sinh^{2}\pars{x} - \sinh^{2}\pars{y}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Note that, by simplicity, I replaced $\ds{x/2 \mapsto x}$ which doesn't matter in the $\ds{x \to 0^{+}}$ limit.

> Lets $\ds{\sinh\pars{y} = \sinh\pars{x}\sin\pars{t}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{x}
{\dd y \over \root{\cosh\pars{x} - \cosh\pars{y}}} =
\root{2}\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd t \over \root{1 + x\sin^{2}\pars{t}}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd t = \bbx{\ds{\root{2}\pi \over 2}}
\approx 2.2214
\end{align}
In the line \eqref{2} squared root, I replaced
$\ds{\sinh^{2}\pars{x} \mapsto x}$ which doesn't matter in the
$\ds{x \to 0^{+}}$ limit.

> Note that $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ x\ >\ 0~}}$

\begin{align}
&0 < \verts{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd t \over \root{1 + x\sin^{2}\pars{t}}} - \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd t} <
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\root{1 + x\sin^{2}\pars{t}} - 1 \over \root{1 + x\sin^{2}\pars{t}}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
x\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\sin^{2}\pars{t} \over
\root{1 + x\sin^{2}\pars{t}}\bracks{\root{1 + x\sin^{2}\pars{t}} + 1}}\,\dd t <
x\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{1 \over 1 \times 2}\,\dd t
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ x\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\to}\,\,\, {\large 0}
\end{align}

Comment: Very well done! (+1)

Comment: Felix, there is an error in the development that won't prevent a quick fix.  Note that with the substitution $\sinh(y)=\sinh(x)\sin(t)$ we have $$\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sinh^2(x)-\sinh^2(y)}}\,dy=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)\sin^2(t)}}\,dt$$And the limit of this is still $\pi/2$

Comment: @Dr.MV Everything is fine. Because $x \to 0^{+}$, I replaced $x/2$ by $x$ in line $\left(1\right)$. Again, because $x \to 0^{+}$, I replaced $\sinh^{2}\left(x\right)$ by $x$ in line $\left(2\right)$. It'll, of course, be different in absence of the $x \to 0^{+}$-limit. Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.MV I evaluated the integral without the limit $x \to 0^{+}$ in [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2193003/85343).

Comment: Felix, I understand that in the limit, it doesn't matter.  But for sake of clarity, you mighy consider mentioning that there are implicit substitutions that you've made.  (+1) for this and (+1) for the answer in the link.

Comment: @Dr.MV I understand your point. I already added comments below lines $\left(1\right)$ and $\left(2\right)$ to clarify the steps I took. Thanks.